# Nodejs function returns undefined, although callback parameter has a value

Tags: mysql, node.js, function, undefined

I have following code:

```
const get = (ip,key) => {
mysql.query(`SELECT content FROM sessions WHERE ip = "${ip}" AND name = "${key}" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`,(err,result) => {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log('Callback:',result[0].content)
    return result[0].content
})
}

console.log('Return:',get('10.0.0.9','test'))
```

It produces following output:

```
Return: undefined
Callback: test content
```

Why doesn't my function return anything?

Comment: because it is not the `get` function that returns the value.  The callback is a different function,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value "test content" is what's actually returned by the handler (or callback) you pass to `mysql.query()`.

Your function **get** actually do not return anything.

You are dealing with an asynchronous function.
There is several way to solve your problem.

Simplest one, would be to pass a third argument to your get function, a callback function an call it in your mysql handler. Something like:

```
const get = (ip,key,callback) => {
mysql.query(`SELECT content FROM sessions WHERE ip = "${ip}" AND name = "${key}" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`,(err,result) => {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log('Callback:',result[0].content);
    // Call you custom callback here to forward result
    callback( result[0].content );
})
}

get('10.0.0.9','test', (result) => console.log('Return:', result));
```

An other approach, more modern would be to use [Promise](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)

And the most 'up to date' solution would be to use a [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)